# AddressBook Program Remove And Search Method Null Pointer Exceptions

Tags: java, class, methods

EDIT5:My remove() method asks for a name to remove, and no matter what name I enter in it will delete the latest name in the array. I'm not sure how to fix this, and my search array will ask for a name and then declare a Null Pointer Exception error. The rest of my code is provided below.

```
 case 3: //Remove a contact
        System.out.print("Full name to remove: ");
        Scanner rs = new Scanner(System.in);
        String deleteName = rs.nextLine();
        a1.remove(deleteName);
        break;

case 4: //search a contact
        System.out.print("Full name to search: ");
        Scanner ss = new Scanner(System.in);
        String searchName = ss.nextLine();
        a1.search(searchName);
        break;
```

EDIT4: Figured out the initialization problem.. can't believe I missed something so simple. My program now works nearly perfect, besides for my remove function, which encounters a null Pointer exception. Can someone explain to me why this happens? Also I've updated the code

EDIT3: I now have nothing yelling at me in my Contact and AddressBook classes. I just need to know how to make my methods in main work. As someone pointed out in the comments I need to initialize my methods and classes. Can someone please tell me where I need to put my constructor so these methods will work? I have them placed in multiple areas of my program already to no avail.

I'm working on an AddressBook program for my java class. I've constructed everything, but my methods in other classes are giving me some difficulty(I made all my methods public and my class specific variables private). Also I would like some feedback on how I constructed my methods. I was given a rough outline of what methods to use here:

```
Contact
-firstName:String
-lastName:String
-phone:String
+Contact(firstName:String,lastName:String, phone:String)
+getFullName():String
+getLastName():String
+getPhone():String
+setFirstName(firstName:String):void
+setLastName(lastName:String):void
+setPhone(phone:String):void
+equals(o:Object):boolean #currently not sure how to do this method
+toString():String

AddressBook class
-contacts:Contact[]
- count:int;
-fileName:String
+AddressBook(fileName:String)
+add(Contact c):boolean
+remove(fullName:String):boolean
+search(fullName:String):Contact
+display():void
+load():boolean
+save():boolean
+search(String fullName):boolean
```

Here is my code:

Contact class code:

```
public class Contact {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String phone;

public Contact(String firstName, String lastName, String phone) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getFullName(){
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}

public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName(){
    return lastName;
}

public String getPhone(){
    return phone;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName){
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public void setPhone(String phone){
    this.phone = phone;
}

/*public boolean equals(Contact o){ //not sure how to use this method, tips/suggestions?

}*/

public String toString(){
    return firstName + ":" + lastName + ":" + phone;
}   
}
```

AddressBook Class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AddressBook {
private Contact[] contacts = new Contact[100];
private int count = 0;
private String fileName;

public AddressBook(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public boolean add(Contact c) {
    // Checks to see if the array is full
    if (count > 99) {
        return false;
    }
    // Adds the new contact into the array
    contacts[count] = c;

    // increment count
    count++;
    return true;
}

public boolean remove(String deleteName) {          //switched fullName to deleteName to avoid duplicate variable problems
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if(contacts[i].getFullName() == deleteName) {
            contacts[i] = null;
            contacts[i] = contacts[i-1];
        }
    }
    count--;
    return true;
}


 public Contact search(String searchName){      //switched fullName to searchName to avoid duplicate variable problems in the main class
     for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){ 
         if (contacts[i].getFullName() == searchName) {
             return contacts[i]; 
             } 
         } return null; 
        }


public void display() {
    System.out.println("Name               Phone Number");      //setting up the format for displaying contacts
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {                           //for loop printing out and displaying contacts
        System.out.println(contacts[i].getFirstName() + " "
                + contacts[i].getLastName() + "\t\t"
                + contacts[i].getPhone());
    }
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
}

public boolean load() {
    //reads the file address.txt and loads it
    try {
        File fr = new File(fileName);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(fr);
        while(s.hasNextLine()) {
            String oStore = s.nextLine();                                   //Storing the line of string here so it can be split
            String[] aStore = oStore.split(":");                            //Splits oStore up and inputs the values into constructor
            contacts[count]=new Contact(aStore[0], aStore[1], aStore[2]);   
            count++;//increments count each contact
        }
        s.close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean save() {
    // Writes the new contact into the file address.txt
    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
            fw.write(contacts[i].getFirstName() + ":"
                    + contacts[i].getLastName() + ":"
                    + contacts[i].getPhone() + "\n");
        }
        fw.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/*public boolean search(String searchName) {    //switched fullName to searchName to avoid duplicate variable problems in the main class
    for(int i = 0; i <contacts.length; i++){ 
         if (contacts[i].getFullName() == searchName) {
             return contacts[i].getFullName() + contacts[i].getPhone(); 
             } 
         }
    return true;
}*/
}
```

Main Class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    AddressBook a1 = new AddressBook("address.txt");


    boolean pQuit = false; //boolean value to end the program

    a1.load();
    System.out.println("Welcome. Address book is loaded.");
    System.out.println("");

    do{
     //Setting up the initial menu
    System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
    System.out.println("1)  Display all contacts");
    System.out.println("2)  Add a contact");
    System.out.println("3)  Remove a contact");
    System.out.println("4)  Search a contact");
    System.out.println("5)  Exit");
    System.out.println("Your choice: ");

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); //Scanner for user's choice
    int choice = s.nextInt(); //User picks menu choice
    System.out.println("\n");//line break

    switch(choice){
    case 1: //Display all contacts
        a1.display();
        break;
    case 2: //Add a contact
        System.out.print("First name:");
        String firstName = s.next(); //Stores first name in firstName
        System.out.print("Last name:");
        String lastName = s.next(); //Stores last name in lastName
        System.out.print("Phone number:");
        String phone = s.next();
        a1.add(new Contact(firstName,lastName,phone));
        System.out.println("Contact added.");
        break;
    case 3: //Remove a contact
        System.out.print("Full name to remove: ");
        Scanner rs = new Scanner(System.in);
        String deleteName = rs.nextLine();
        a1.remove(deleteName);
        break;
    case 4: //search a contact
        System.out.print("Full name to search: ");
        Scanner ss = new Scanner(System.in);
        String searchName = ss.nextLine();
        a1.search(searchName);
        break;
    case 5: //exit the program
        a1.save();
        System.out.println("Addres book is saved to file.");
        pQuit = true;
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("That is not a valid input.");
    }
    }while (pQuit == false);
}
}
```

Right now in my main method none of the methods I have called work because they are undefined. Same instance happened when I tried to use the contacts array in my +equals(o:Object):boolean method. All help is much appreciated, and if you see anything wrong in my methods or anything at all I could fix and improve please let me know!

Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT1: Also please note the two search methods I was given. I pretty much constructed the same code for both. Eclipse right now is yelling at me telling me to change the name of the methods. I would like to know if I constructed the methods incorrectly, or why I would be given two of the same named methods to use in my program.

EDIT2: Updated to my new code. Changed a couple things, methods still do not work though.

Comment: look up the difference between static and non-static methods to see why Eclipse says your methods are undefined.

Comment: Also, yes, you need to rename one or both of your search methods. If you didn't, how would Java know which one you were trying to call?

Comment: I know what the difference is, I've done more than one java program like this and not used static methods. If I change everything to static methods that would really mess up my program is what I'm concerned about. Could I just remove a search method and instead of making changes to one? They perform literally the exact same operation.

Comment: OK right. But to use non-static methods you need to instantiate an object first.

Comment: Can you explain instantiation to me please?

Comment: It's the thing where you go Object x = new Object().

Comment: If the user is the one who enters these objects how should I initialize my program?

Comment: Pass the user's values through the constructor...

Comment: Where should I do this in my program to make all my methods work? I'm still not 100% understanding. I've changed a couple aspects of my program. I'll update the main post so it's visible.

Comment: Suggestion: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: Like I said, I already know the basics, I just don't know where, in my code to input this so it will make everything work jointly and correctly...

Comment: @fdsa  Hey thanks for the help, I finally figured out what you were talking about. Boy I feel stupid. I've done that a million times, but totally blanked on it while creating this program.